# vba - properly passing range value to a function

Tags: vba, excel

in my application i call a function and pass 4 values to calculate a cell adress:

```
nettowertadresse = searchAdress(Dateiname, CurrentSheet, "Nettowert", Range("A1:C60"))
```

function:

```
Function searchAdress(inputworkbook As String, inputsheet As String, inputsearchtext As String, inputrange As Range) As Range

  With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange)
      Set searchAdress = .Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
  End With

End Function
```

now the problem is that i get error 1004 "application defined or object defined error" and i think that maybe the range is not properly passed because the debugger shows no value for the variable "inputrange" when jumping to the function. please give some advice on how to make this function work. thanks.

Comment: It seems that the variable `inputRange` is entering the function `As Range` but for the use you do should rather be `As String`. What is exactly the value you pass to the function (just give an example)?

Comment: as seen above, i pass: Range("A1:C60")

Comment: You're wrong when you pass the range but then you want to use just its address (which is a string). Below you have two good answers, I would use Richard's one as it allows you to use the function still keeping the input as Range (so you don't have to change much your code if this function is already spread in other parts of the code)

Comment: yeah both of them work but they dont return a range. "searchAdress" then contains the string "nettowert".

Comment: I updated my answer (for completeness) to show your other bug, and linked it to your follow-up question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function, `searchAddress`, declares `inputrange as Range`. This means that the object inside your function is a `Range` object.

So you should not be using it as `.Range(inputrange)`. Instead try using this code, which treats it correctly as a `Range` object:

```
Function searchAdress(inputworkbook As String, inputsheet As String, inputsearchtext As String, inputrange As Range) As Range

    With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet)
        Set searchAdress = inputrange.Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

End Function
```

---

Also note that there is another bug in your code that calls this function. You need to use the keyword `Set` when assigning the return value to your `nettowertadresse` variable:

```
Set nettowertadresse = searchAdress(Dateiname, CurrentSheet, "Nettowert", Range("A1:BA2"))
```

Otherwise you will experience Run-time error '91', which you mention in [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843640/383414).

Answer (score 2):

you add a Range to a rangeobject in your function, your function looks like this then:

```
  With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet).Range(Range("A1:C60"))
      Set searchAdress = .Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
  End With
```

You should change this:

```
Function searchAdress(inputworkbook As String, inputsheet As String, inputsearchtext As String, inputrange As String) As Range

  With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet).Range(inputrange)
      Set searchAdress = .Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
  End With

End Function
```

And then pass this to the function:

```
nettowertadresse = searchAdress(Dateiname, CurrentSheet, "Nettowert", "A1:C60")
```

Comment: that seems to work but i need an address returned. so far, it seems that the variable searchAdress inherits the value "nettowert" but not an adress. i thought that .find returns an adress. what am i doing wrong? getting error 91 btw

Comment: is this still a problem? or it this fixed with the other answer you got?

Comment: debugger says that the value in searchAdress is a Range but it contains the value "nettowert"

Comment: ah I see, you get the value in the cell but you need the address. you could try this to check `MsgBox(searchAdress.Address)`

Comment: yes, the msgbox returns the correct value. now how can i return it via the function?

Comment: also i am getting error 91 saying that an object variable or with block variable has not been set when it jumps to the END FUNCTION.

Comment: Function searchAdress(inputworkbook As String, inputsheet As String, inputsearchtext As String, inputrange As Range) As Range

Dim temp1 As Range

    With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet)
        Set temp1 = inputrange.Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
        searchAdress = temp1.Address
    End With

End Function

Comment: actually i tried it with another range variable object that passes the adress to searchAdress and that is the problem

Comment: nice (:! you could return it like `set searchAdress = searchAdress.Address` for example