# vba - returning a range value from a function

Tags: vba, excel

i would like to pass a range value to a function and then return the resulting range value back to my sub.

sub:

```
Dim nettowertadresse As Range
```

and

```
nettowertadresse = searchAdress(Dateiname, CurrentSheet, "Nettowert", Range("A1:BA2"))
```

function:

```
Function searchAdress(inputworkbook As String, inputsheet As String, inputsearchtext As String, inputrange As Range) As Range

  With Workbooks(inputworkbook).Sheets(inputsheet)
      Set searchAdress = inputrange.Find(inputsearchtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
  End With

End Function
```

The first problem is that i don´t get a range value in the function. I think that I need the .adress in searchAdress but it does not work that way. maybe with another object that passes the adress into searchAdress? but in any case i get error 91. please advise on how to return the adress from the found cell in the function back to the variable nettowertadresse in my sub.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
2. not seeing that you have a `Range` object being returned

### 1 - Run-time error '91'

For the first error, the reason is because of the way you are calling your `Function`. As Fratyx points out, [you need to use the keyword `Set` when calling `searchAdress()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842330/383414).

You can also see this in:

- [What is the difference between dim and set in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872339/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-and-set-in-vba)
- [Returning a Range from a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377971/returning-a-range-from-a-function)
- [Can a VBA function in Excel return a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439510/can-a-vba-function-in-excel-return-a-range)

The reason for this is that you are trying to assign an object result to your variable. In VBA when setting objects, you use the `Set` keyword.

### 2 - not seeing a `Range` object

The code **does** return a `Range`object as required. You can confirm this by some debug test code like:

```
Set nettowertadresse = searchAdress(Dateiname, CurrentSheet, "Nettowert", Range("A1:BA2"))
nettowertadresse.Select
```

or

```
MsgBox nettowertaddresse.Address
```

This will select the cell which has your word in it, or display the address in a popup box.

You are probably using `MsgBox()` or hovering over the variable in the editor, which is returning the actual range value (`nettowertadresse.value`)

---

Both of these issues are related the your question from the other day, which addresses these exact same issues, but before you started to use your own function:

- [Trouble with vba error 91 when using With, Range and .Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784347/trouble-with-vba-error-91-when-using-with-range-and-find)

See how the answer there relates directly to the explanations I give you here. The difference is that you are using your own function now, but the basic underlying issues are still the same.

Answer (score 3):

In call to `searchAddress` write

```
Set nettowertadresse = searchAdress(.....)
```

The problem is in assigning the return value of `searchAdress` to `nettowertAddress`